# Optimising without templates

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, chess, micro-optimization

I'm writing a chess engine, and I have a function that looks like this:

```
U64 find_moves(Piece type, Team side, uint8_t square, U64 occupied) {
    switch (type) {
        case PAWN: {
            U64 result = 0;
            result |= occupied & bb_normal_moves::pawn_caps[side][square];
            if (!(occupied & bb_normal_moves::pawn_moves_x1[side][square])) {
                result |= bb_normal_moves::pawn_moves_x1[side][square];
                if (!(occupied & bb_normal_moves::pawn_moves_x2[side][square])) {
                    result |= bb_normal_moves::pawn_moves_x2[side][square];
                }
            }
            return result;
        }
        case KNIGHT:
            return bb_normal_moves::knight_moves[square];
        case BISHOP:
            return bb_magics::bishop_moves(square, occupied);
        case ROOK:
            return bb_magics::rook_moves(square, occupied);
        case QUEEN:
            return bb_magics::bishop_moves(square, occupied) | bb_magics::rook_moves(square, occupied);
        case KING:
            return bb_normal_moves::king_moves[square];
    }

    return 0; // Can't happen
}
```

It essentially delegates to another function call depending on the `type` parameter. In many places around the program, this function is called after looping through different `Piece` values, which happens to be an `enum`.

Unfortunately, that means that this function is called each time in that loop, so a lot of CPU time is wasted in this function branching.

What I'd like to do is change this function to allow the compiler to optimise the calls:

```
template <Piece type> U64 find_moves(Team side, uint8_t square, U64 occupied)
```

but then my loops would not compile as the target of the function call cannot be resolved at compile time.

Is there a way of optimising this function without manually unrolling all of my loops?

EDIT: Here is an example of one of the loops that calls `find_moves`:

```
for (uint8_t piece = 1; piece < 6; piece++) {
    move.info.piece = piece;
    U64 bb_piece = board.bb_pieces[team][piece];

    while (bb_piece) {
        uint8_t from = pop_bit(team, bb_piece);
        move.info.from = from;

        U64 bb_targets = find_moves((Piece) piece, team, from, board.bb_all) & mask;

        while (bb_targets) {
            uint8_t to = pop_bit(x_team, bb_targets);
            move.info.to = to;

            buf[buf_size++] = move;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: *"Is there a way of optimising this function without manually unrolling all of my loops?"* Modern compilers are very good at determining when to unroll a loop and at unroll them when it's appropriate.

Comment: If a constant `type` argument is given, it's extremely likely that the call will be inlined and optimized out.

Comment: Honestly, this looks pretty much optimal. You can always fiddle with the code to see if it has any effect, but I doubt that you'll get significantly faster than what you have here.

Comment: It seems like you are looking for [`full explicit template specialization`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_specialization) which lets you provide distinct implementations for specific sets of template arguments.

Comment: I'm not completely sure; profiling seems to suggest that huge amount of CPU time is spent inside that find_moves function, even though it just delegates to another function or performs an array lookup

Comment: @konsolas If this is the primary function you are calling in a loop, then yes, a huge amount of time is spent inside this function. Profilers usually give the amount of time spent in a function, *including the time spent in functions that it calls*

Comment: @konsolas That would be surprising. What optimization flags are you using? What compiler and what version of it are you uisng?

Comment: I'm using mingw-w64, gcc 8.1.0, flags ```"-march=native -Ofast -g -static -std=c++17 -pedantic"```

Comment: Some time is spent in the functions called by `find_moves`, but the time spent in `find_moves` itself is much higher than the combined time of the callees. I'm not entirely sure if i can embed images here.

Comment: Is `type` dynamically provided? If so, a `template` based solution can't help you.

Comment: I've given an example of an use case of find_moves. The function called is always the same on the same iteration of the loop

Comment: @konsolas Chandler Carruths talk ["Going Nowhere Faster"](https://youtu.be/2EWejmkKlxs) could help you find what's happening. There might be a bunch of cache misses or a bunch of branch prediction fails or something like that. Also, you might find [Mike Acton's talk on Data Oriented Design](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rX0ItVEVjHc) helpful.

Comment: @konsolas With your given example, I'd consider trying making it into a tight loop that just calls `find_moves` and stores the result for reference later. It takes more memory, but it could potentially help avoid cache misses and branch mispredictions.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux: Modern compilers aren't that good.  gcc doesn't enable `-funroll-loops` by default.  You need to compile with profile-guided optimization (`-fprofile-use`) so it knows which loops are actually hot for it to ever unroll loops (except for fully unrolling small loops with a small constant iteration count).  PGO may help a lot.

Comment: @konsolas: Do you have this function in a header where it can inline and optimize away a compile-time constant `type` arg, for cases where it is constant?  Or link-time optimization should solve the same problem.  Your loop looks like it will be prone to branch mispredicts.  Profile your code with performance counters to see if the time is spent on branch misses, cache misses, or what.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something - the body of the example loop you have can become the body of a function where piece is a template argument; then you need to call the function 6 times; if you consider that unrolling, then I guess you're stuck with the unrolling unless you got to great lengths with boost::fusion or something like that.

Comment: I have the function in a .cpp file with a prototype in a header used by other source files. I haven't tried profile-guided optimization yet, but I will do so. Will the fact that the function is not in the header significantly limit optimisation?

Comment: @StefanAtev that seems to be a good compromise, I'll try it.

Answer (score 1):

Given that the values of your `Piece` enum are from 1 to 6, you can use templates, `std::make_index_sequence`, `std::index_sequence` to unroll.

Sorry but I can only prepare a minimal example (no `move`, no `board`, etc).

If you call something as

```
foo(std::make_index_sequence<6U>{});
```

in `foo()` you can call another function with singles values (you tagged C++17 so you can use template folding)

```
template <std::size_t ... Ps>
void foo (std::index_sequence<Ps...> const &)
 { (bar<Ps>(), ...); }
```

My idea is that in `bar()` you can place the content of the body of the `for (uint8_t piece = 1; piece < 6; piece++)` loop of your example; I place only the call to a trivial (no other arguments) `find_moves()` function.

```
template <std::size_t Ps>
void bar ()
 { find_moves<pieces(1+Ps)>(); }
```

Now you can develop six `find_moves()` template function using full specialization (I write only `std::cout` messages; you, using other arguments, can place the content of the `case`s in your `switch`.

```
template <pieces P>
void find_moves ();

template <>
void find_moves<Pawn> ()
 { std::cout << "Case Pawn" << std::endl; }

template <>
void find_moves<Knight> ()
 { std::cout << "Case Knight" << std::endl; }

template <>
void find_moves<Bishop> ()
 { std::cout << "Case Bishop" << std::endl; }

template <>
void find_moves<Rook> ()
 { std::cout << "Case Rook" << std::endl; }

template <>
void find_moves<Queen> ()
 { std::cout << "Case Queen" << std::endl; }

template <>
void find_moves<King> ()
 { std::cout << "Case King" << std::endl; }
```

The following is a full compiling example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
#include <type_traits>

enum pieces { Pawn = 1, Knight, Bishop, Rook, Queen, King };

template <pieces P>
void find_moves ();

template <>
void find_moves<Pawn> ()
 { std::cout << "Case Pawn" << std::endl; }

template <>
void find_moves<Knight> ()
 { std::cout << "Case Knight" << std::endl; }

template <>
void find_moves<Bishop> ()
 { std::cout << "Case Bishop" << std::endl; }

template <>
void find_moves<Rook> ()
 { std::cout << "Case Rook" << std::endl; }

template <>
void find_moves<Queen> ()
 { std::cout << "Case Queen" << std::endl; }

template <>
void find_moves<King> ()
 { std::cout << "Case King" << std::endl; }

template <std::size_t Ps>
void bar ()
 { find_moves<pieces(1+Ps)>(); }

template <std::size_t ... Ps>
void foo (std::index_sequence<Ps...> const &)
 { (bar<Ps>(), ...); }

int main ()
 {
   foo(std::make_index_sequence<6U>{});
 }
```

Comment: you are a template specialist. (+1) :)